# What is the difference between univariate post-hoc tests after MANOVA and usual ANOVAs?

Tags: anova, spss, post-hoc, manova

When I run a $2 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6$ (Sex $\times$ AgeGroup $\times$ HighestDegree $\times$ Ethnicity) MANOVA (with 20 dependent variables) in SPSS, it presents tests of between subjects effects for each of the IVs and their interactions after the main MANOVA stats as a kind of post hoc.

I thought these tests were $2 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6$ factorial ANOVAs for each of the DVs examined in the MANOVA. But when I run those factorial ANOVAs separately, I get completely different results! (The $F$ values in the MANOVA post hoc are generally higher than the $F$ values resulting from the separate factorial ANOVAs.)

Why is that? I know I shouldn't trust the main MANOVA stats (Pillai's trace, etc.) because the cell sample sizes are way too small, but I'm at a loss as to why the post hocs from the MANOVA are different from factorial ANOVAs for each of the DVs.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your situation, & I don't have SPSS, but in general, MANOVA can be thought of as an ANOVA performed on a specific linear combination of your DVs which is basically never equivalent to exactly one of your DVs w/ the others dropped.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that - I didn't expect the MANOVA to be equivalent to (any of) the ANOVAs for each of the DVs. What I expected was that each of the post hoc tests presented alongside the MANOVA, that analyzed the effects of each of the IVs (and IV interactions) on each of the DVs separately, would be equivalent to one of the ANOVAs for each of the DVs separately. But that expectation turned out to be wrong, which surprised me.

Comment: (+1) This is a weird effect. I would also be interested in knowing what is going on here. Univariate post-hocs after MANOVA *are* standard ANOVAs, there should be no difference.